# constructor call valid only as the first statement in an instance constructor?

Tags: vb.net, constructor

So, I write this code, and it gives me an error. (Constructor Call is Valid only as the first statement in an instance constructor.)

```
Public Class PossibleMove
    Public importance As Integer
    Public x1,y1,x2,y2 As Integer
    Public match As Match

    Public Sub New(ByVal _PossibleMove As PossibleMove)
        With _PossibleMove
            Me.New(.x1, .y1, .x2, .y2, .match)  'Gives an error
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(x1 As Integer, y1 As Integer, x2 As Integer, y2 As Integer, ByVal _Match As Match)
        Me.importance = 0
        '  ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I remove the `With _PossibleMove` thing, it works as expected, and so, is not much of an issue.
The problem is, that I do NOT get an error with the following code, even though its neccesarily the same thing(??)

```
Public Class Match

    ' Data members...

    Public Sub New(ByVal _Match As Match)
        With _Match
            Me.New(.xBegin, .xEnd, .yBegin, .yEnd, .triggerX, .triggerY, .color)
            '  No error here!  ^^^
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(_xBegin As Integer, _xEnd As Integer, _yBegin As Integer, _yEnd As Integer, _triggerX As Integer, _triggerY As Integer, _Color As Integer)
        Me.xBegin = _xBegin
        ''' More stuff here...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can someone please tell me why the second block of code compiles but the first one doesn't.

Also, why does a Constructor call has to be the very first statement?
Thanks.

EDIT :

> Does the Match class have any classes as data members? If not, I'd guess that's the reason. The first constructor in PossibleMove has to construct the match object, so your Me.New isn't the first thing being done. – Brian Hooper

Well, the Match Class does not have any "user-defined object" type data members, so maybe your guess is right.
But if that were the case, the code wouldn't compile even if I removed the `With _PossibleMove` thing, because even then the match object is being constructed, and so, `Me.New()` isn't the first thing being done.
And that is not the case (meaning it compiles on remoing the `With _PossibleMove` and changing it to `Me.New(_PossibleMove.x1, _PossibleMove.y1, _PossibleMove.x2, _PossibleMove.y2, _PossibleMove.match)` .

Comment: Does the `Match` class have any classes as data members? If not, I'd guess that's the reason. The first constructor in PossibleMove has to construct the `match` object, so your Me.New isn't the first thing being done.

Comment: Well, the Match Class does not have any "user-defined object" type data members, so maybe your guess is right.
But if that were the case, the code wouldn't compile even if I removed the `With _PossibleMove` thing, because even then the match object is being constructed, and so, `Me.New()` isn't the first thing being done.
And that is not the case (meaning it compiles on remoing the `With _PossibleMove` and changing it to `Me.New(_PossibleMove.x1, _PossibleMove.y1, _PossibleMove.x2, _PossibleMove.y2, _PossibleMove.match)`

Comment: Well, yes, if you remove the `With`, then the `Me.New` becomes the first statement, and all you are doing is redirecting the constructor. That, I think, is why it has to be the first line.